# Runtime error in pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, googletest

I am doing unit testing using google C++ testing tools. I am a novice C programmer as well as tester.
The following is my code snippet :

```
TEST_F (def_fix, SR_M_T) {
    I_M_S * arg;
    RM__S_F_R_T* message_data;
    char mT[MAX_M_T_LENGTH] = "data";

    strcpy(message_data->mT,mT);
    message_data->rUID[0] = '\0';
    message_data->uT[0] = '\0';

    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(RM__S_F_R_T)+2];
    memcpy(&buffer[2],message_data,sizeof(RM__S_F_R_T));

    buffer[0] = 1;      //This assignment is not important for this test
    buffer[1] = 2;          //This assignment is not important for this test

    arg->payload_data = buffer;

    handleSR(arg);
}
```

What the above does is creating an incoming message. This incoming message `arg` is to be used as parameter to call a function `handleSR (void *).`
`def_fix` is a default fixture class which contains `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` and nothing fancy in them.

`RM__S_F_R_T` is a structure which contains and 3 strings.
`I_M_S` is a structure containing a pointer to `RM__S_F_R_T`.

When I google test this, it gives a segmentation error. However when I change:
`RM__S_FR_R_ * message_data;`  to  `RM__S_FR_R_ message_data;`and use `.` operator instead of `->` operator, things tend to work. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Your `message_data` pointer variable is being used uninitialized.

Comment: So it's a runtime error, not a compilation error?

Comment: @jerry, yes, a segmentation fault is always a runtime error.  If a compiler gets a segmentation fault it means that the compiler crashed.

Comment: @StephenRasku The question has been edited a few times, the original title was "Compilation error in pointer to structure". I was trying to clear up the discrepancy between that and the last paragraph before editing, I hadn't taken a good look at the code yet.

Comment: @jerry Fair enough.  I didn't realize that.

Comment: @StephenRasku no worries, I appreciate that you were trying to help me out :)

Answer (score 2):

These two statements:

```
RM__S_F_R_T* message_data;
strcpy(message_data->mT,mT);
```

are the culprit. You never initialise the `RM__S_F_R_T` (who designed this thing?!) pointer. When not using it as a pointer, you create an instance on the stack that you can use.

To fix either don't use a pointer (you already found that out), or allocate memory:

```
message_data = malloc(sizeof(RM__S_F_R_T));
```

don't forget to `free(message_data)` when you are done with the instance, or you'll leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declare `message_data` to be a pointer, but don't point it at anything. So then it will point to a random memory location, causing undefined behavior when you dereference it.

Either declare it as not a pointer, or allocate memory for it.

Comment: Thanks. Understood. But If I still want to use it as a pointer what should I do? Just curious.
Also my function handleSR() isn't returning anything. So how do I assert something or expect something? I read in some posts that assert for those variables which are getting modified by this function but I dont know how to access the results of this functio. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user2435273 I don't see the need to use a pointer in this case, but if you must have it as a pointer then you need to allocate memory for it, e.g. `RM__S_F_R_T* message_data = malloc(sizeof(RM__S_F_R_T));`

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided memory to RM__S_F_R_T*.Use message_data after

```
message_data = (RM__S_F_R_T*)malloc(sizeof(RM__S_F_R_T));
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `I_M_S * arg` and `RM__S_F_R_T* message_data`:

```
I_M_S * arg = malloc(sizeof(I_M_S));
RM__S_F_R_T* message_data = malloc(sizeof(RM__S_F_R_T));
```

Also, make sure you don't use these allocated pointers after the scope of function `TEST_F()` because you assign `arg->payload_data = buffer` where scope of localized variable `buffer` ends after the function `TEST_F()`.

And so, free these pointers before you leave `TEST_F()`:

free(arg);
free(message_data);

Answer (score 0):

`message_data` doesn't point to anything. You need to pass an initialised RM__S_F_R_T struct pointer to your function as an argument or initialise it inside the function itself.

Further, I presume `message_data->mT` is a char pointer. It's not pointing to anything currently.

You can assign space for it using `malloc`, or if it's a char array then make sure it's big enough to hold `mT` into it (provided its struct is already initialised).

The above applies to all of `message_data`'s members.

As the other posters have already mentioned, don't forget to `free()` anything you have `malloc()`-ed.

Comment: Also my function handleSR() isn't returning anything. So how do I assert something or expect something? I read in some posts that assert for those variables which are getting modified by this function but I dont know how to access the results of this functio. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h
Can you not put `assert` statements inside `handleSR()`? Or maybe you can change it to return something? Like: `assert(handleSR(msg) != NULL);` if we assume `handleSR()` returns a pointer to a resource.

Comment: What handleSR() does is takes an input message, processes a database, finds a some rows/columns and then creates a message similar to the message I created (I_M_S * arg;) and then broadcasts. 
What I would prefer doing is somehow access one of the local variables of the function which stores some kind of status and check it.I cant change the API and hence cant make the functin return something.

Comment: Can I access the local variables of a function somehow using a pointer to that function?

Comment: Local variables do you mean `arg` in `handleSR(arg)`? Since it's a pointer, you can do `assert(arg != NULL);` right before you call `handleSR(arg);`. Otherwise I can refer you to a debugger (like 'gdb') which would you allow you to step in `handleSR()` so you can inspect it line by line.
At the moment you're not doing anything with `I_M_S * arg` and so the `assert` will fail. Make sure it's initialised properly before going anywhere :)

Comment: You can't just reach inside a function that you call from an external library through your code. You can however step through the code using a debugger. Using `gdb` set a breakpoint on the line calling `handleSR(arg);`. Then step in by typing `s` and then type `next` to inspect each line individually once you're inside. For this to work best, compile your application with the `-g` option. Here's more information on `gdb` - http://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs331/gdbtutorial.html